# Magento-2 how to change image frame

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, product-view, white-screen

I want to change the white image frame with my own image. is there any way i can do that because that white background looks so cheap. please if anyone knows how to set an image on image frame and replace that white space with my image, help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a custom theme or you are using the Luma theme?

If you have buy a theme you have to contact with the creator or to read the Documentetion.

If not read here how to ovveride your theme http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html.

In second case you have to know a little bit CSS.

I hope that I help you. For anything else, feel free to ask.